# "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'" error on LUIS call

Tags: c#, frameworks, azure-language-understanding

I am getting this error on LUIS call:

```
"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"

Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 4.05:29:12.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your authoring/starter key is only allowed 1000 endpoint queries a month and you have hit the maximum amounts of requests for your LUIS starter key. You need to create a [LUIS subscription key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-azure-subscription) (free or paid) and use that key when making endpoint queries. If you are making endpoint queries from a bot or another client application, you need to change the LUIS endpoint key there.